# How to delete object through it's pointer stored in std::list?

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco

I am using Poco::Thread.

```
 std::list<Thread*> threads;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
       Thread* t=new Thread();
       RunnableClient* r=new RunnableClient(); //this class has run method()
       threads.push_back(t);
       t.start(*r);
    }
    std::list<Thread*>::iterator it;
    for (it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it){
       if((*it)->isRunning() == false){
          threads.erase(it,it);
          }
     }
```

erase() method used in the above function just removes the reference to the object, but does not free up the space allocated to the Thread objects. How to free the space allocated to the Thread objects ?

Comment: typically there is a `join()` or `detach()` method on threads. Check the docs. Also, you would probably want to store that in a `std::unique_ptr` to clean up once it is no longer referenced.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to handle this is to use smart pointer
like `std::unique_ptr`

also you must call `join` or `detach` on your thread before his destructor is called

asumming c++11 and `#include <memory>`

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Thread> > threads;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
       RunnableClient* r=new RunnableClient(); //this class has run method()
       threads.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Thread>());
       threads.back().start(*r);
    }
    //need to join or detatch thread before destoying them
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Thread> >::iterator it;
    for (it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it){
       if((*it)->isRunning() == false){
          threads.erase(it,it);
          }
     }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "need to join or detach thread to make joinable" ?can you explain more or provide some code?

Comment: I think you mean that the thread must not be joinable -- you must either call `join()` on the thread or call `detach()` before destroying it, which both make `joinable()` return false. See for example the destructor of `std::thread` in `libstdc++`: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/thread#L135

Comment: @PaulBelanger: You seem to be basing your comment on `std::thread`, but OP says he's using Poco::Thread, which is somewhat different (e.g., I don't believe it has a `detach` at all).